# How do I turn this WHERE Query into a SubQuery in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

```
SELECT a.CLIENTID,
       a.CLIENTNAME,
       a.CREATEDATE,
       b.AREACODE,
       b.PHONENUMBER    
FROM CLIENT a
INNER JOIN PHONE b ON a.CLIENTID = b.CLIENTID
WHERE b.AREACODE = '612'
;
```

This code returns what I am looking for.  However, I want the query to be return the same data using a subquery in the WHERE clause.  Please help me reformat it.  I don't understand how.  Thanks.

EDIT: Using Oracle.  Sorry about the silly question, I need to do it for an assignment.  Can't figure it out.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Mysql, oracle or sql server? They are not the same. And why do you specifically want to use a subquery?

Comment: It's hardly recommended to avoid use of subquery, describe us what you want and we'll find the most appropriate solution without having to use a subquery (if possible)

Comment: What are you trying to do that you believe the subquery will do for you? What results are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change the last part to have a subquery (I will use `in` so you can have multiple values in the `WHERE` clause)

```
SELECT a.CLIENTID,
       a.CLIENTNAME,
       a.CREATEDATE,
       b.AREACODE,
       b.PHONENUMBER    
FROM CLIENT a
INNER JOIN PHONE b ON a.CLIENTID = b.CLIENTID
WHERE b.AREACODE IN 
    /* You can put your query inside the ()s */
    (SELECT TOP 10 AREACODE FROM PHONE)
;
```

Not sure if you are using it for practicing, or real life scenarios, but introducing subqueries can significantly increase the time the script takes to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is not a subquery, but rewriting the JOIN inside of the WHERE clause. Perhaps you wanted to do this?:

```
SELECT a.CLIENTID, a.CLIENTNAME, a.CREATEDATE, b.AREACODE, b.PHONENUMBER
FROM CLIENT a, PHONE b
WHERE a.CLIENTID = b.CLIENTID AND b.AREACODE = '612'
```

It is unclear from your question if this is correct, but this is a way to accomplish the same task while rewriting the WHERE clause.

**EDIT**

This makes the assumption that you actually want to use the value '612'. If you wanted to be able to use any value, you can keep the JOIN and write this:

```
SELECT a.CLIENTID, a.CLIENTNAME, a.CREATEDATE, b.AREACODE, b.PHONENUMBER
FROM CLIENT a
JOIN PHONE b on a.CLIENTID = b.CLIENTID
WHERE b.AREACODE = (SELECT areacode FROM phone WHERE *some condition here* LIMIT 1);
```

This will return 1 specific area code, that matches whatever condition you require. You can match that to the area code in your where clause.

Comment: The first statement is the same as the one in the question, it's just using the old syntax instead of ANSI joins?

Comment: Again, the question was unclear. I was going off the chance that all OP really needed to do was make the same query while rewriting the where clause.

Comment: I see, though they specifically said they needed a subquery for their assignment. <shrug>

Comment: Yeah, I understand where you're coming from. Not the best answer I've ever given, but why not take a shot in the dark. I still don't even know if the second answer does what they want. Saying they need a subquery in the where clause is almost as broad as you can get.

Comment: Yeah, no argument there *8-)

Comment: Did two people on the internet just agree? I think I need to get away from my desk and have some fresh air.